# sse constraint in inline assembly not working

Tags: c++, g++, sse

I am getting some problems while compiling the below code snippet.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

using namespace std;

union mxcsr {
    uint32_t v;
    struct {
        uint32_t  ie : 1;
        uint32_t  de : 1;
        uint32_t  ze : 1;
        uint32_t  oe : 1;
        uint32_t  ue : 1;
        uint32_t  pe : 1;
        uint32_t daz : 1;
        uint32_t  im : 1;
        uint32_t  dm : 1;
        uint32_t  zm : 1;
        uint32_t  om : 1;
        uint32_t  um : 1;
        uint32_t  pm : 1;
        uint32_t  rn : 1;
        uint32_t  rp : 1;
        uint32_t  fz : 1;
        uint32_t rs0 : 15;
    };
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& ostr, mxcsr &m){
    ostr << std::hex << std::showbase;
    ostr << "mxcsr=" << m.v;
    ostr << std::dec << std::noshowbase;
    ostr << " [ie=" << m.ie << ",de=" << m.de
         << ",ze=" << m.ze << ",oe=" << m.oe << ",ue=" << m.ue
         << ",pe=" << m.pe << ",daz=" << m.daz << ",im=" << m.im
         << ",dm=" << m.dm << ",zm=" << m.zm << ",om=" << m.om
         << ",um=" << m.um << ",pm=" << m.pm << ",r-=" << m.rn
         << ",r+=" << m.rp << ",fz=" << m.fz << "] ";
    return ostr;
}

typedef union __attribute__((aligned(16))) vec_t {
    double       f64[2];
    float        f32[4];
    uint64_t     u64[2];
    uint32_t     u32[4];
    uint16_t     u16[8];
    uint8_t      u8[16];
    int64_t      i64[2];
    int32_t      i32[4];
    int16_t      i16[8];
    int8_t       i8[16];
 } vec_t;


float add_vec_32f(float ra, float rb, mxcsr &f){
    vec_t va, vb;
    va.f32[0] = ra; vb.f32[0] = rb;
    asm("addps %[vb], %[va];"
        "stmxcsr %[f];"
        : [va] "+x" (va), [f] "=m" (f)
        : [vb] "xm" (vb)
        :
    );
    return va.f32[0];
}

int main()
{
    mxcsr val;

    float b = add_vec_32f(3.4, 5.6, val);

    std::cout << "b=" << b << " val=" << val << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler complains with this error *"impossible constraint in 'asm'"*. To verify this, I went through the description of ADDPS instruction. It says something like this :-

ADDPS xmm1, xmm2/m128
Add packed single-precision floating-point values from xmm2/m128 to xmm1.

So, the source can be memory address or an xmm register, but destination has to be an xmm register.I guess my constraints kind of agree with that.
Could anyone point me to the possible issue here ?

Thanks.

Comment: "impossible constraint in 'asm'" doesn't sound like the assembler instruction is malformed, but that your constraint is malformed.

Comment: See http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Vector-Extensions.html for how gcc wants vector types to be declared (or include <x86intrin.h> and use __m128d or one of the others).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I am not sure why using the `union` does not work but using a SIMD vector instructions does work, although you would need to add one to the `union`. I was able to get it to work like so:

```
typedef double xmmd __attribute__ ((vector_size (16)));

typedef union __attribute__((aligned(16))) 
vec_t {
    xmmd         xmm ;
    double       f64[2];
    float        f32[4];    
    uint64_t     u64[2];
    uint32_t     u32[4];
    uint16_t     u16[8];
    uint8_t      u8[16];
    int64_t      i64[2];
    int32_t      i32[4];
    int16_t      i16[8];
    int8_t       i8[16];
 } vec_t;

float add_vec_32f(float ra, float rb, mxcsr &f){
    vec_t va, vb;
    va.f32[0] = ra; vb.f32[0] = rb;


     asm("addps %[v2], %[v1];"
        "stmxcsr %[f];"
        : [v1] "+x" (va.xmm), [f] "=m" (f)
        : [v2] "xm" (vb.xmm)
        :
    );

    return va.f32[0];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that will do. Looks like gcc doesn't allow to declare unions as vector types, so this is the sanest way of doing it.

Comment: @vikasC Yeah, inline asm in general can be tricky to fully understand this article has helped me gain a better understanding http://locklessinc.com/articles/gcc_asm/ also if you could accept my answer I would appreciate it